# Issue with opportunity query

Tags: apex, query

I have the following query:

```
Opportunity opp = [SELECT Id, Name, OwnerID, accountID, CreatedBy from Opportunity where CreatedDate<:Date.today() and CreatedBy.UserRoleId=:Inside_Sales.Id  ];
```

And this is the error I'm receiving:

No such column 'CreatedBy' on entity 'Opportunity'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

I need to make the query so it only looks for opportunities that where created by users with a specific role.
How can I use the CreatedBy field in a query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> SELECT Id, Name, OwnerID, accountID, **CreatedBy**

This syntax is invalid. If you just need the user Id, use `CreatedById`, or if you want a specific field from the user object, use the dot-notation (e.g. `CreatedBy.Name`).

Comment: How can I access the user Role ID?  Would it be CreatedBy.Name.UserRoleId?

Comment: @VictorEcheverría Just CreatedBy.UserRoleId. Coincidentally, you're apparently filtering on just a single user role Id, so do you really need this? `CreatedBy.UserRoleId` will be the same as `Inside_Sales.Id`.